# Android: video in webview freezes when running javascript via loadUrl

Tags: javascript, android, video, webview, keypress

I have an app which plays adaptive streaming video in a webview.  The issue is when trying to inject javascript, the video freezes.

HTML:

```
<video src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" height="720" width="1280" />
```

Android:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hello World!');");
```

Answer (score 0):

So this small piece of code worked for me when i was trying to play a video in a webview :

```
      String videoPoP = "http://www.youtube.com/v/A6kCkkLo6Rw?";
      webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      String widthAndHeight = "width=\"" + widthdp + "\" height=\"" + height_new + "\"";            

            String temp = "<object "
                + widthAndHeight
                + ">"
                + "<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>"
                + "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>"
                + "</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>"
                + "</param><embed src='"
                + videoPoP
                + "'"
                + " type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'"
                + widthAndHeight + "></embed></object>";


        webview.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

You can give any values to width and height in the string

Comment: Hi, thanks but the video plays fine.  It freezes when javascript is injected via loadurl.

Comment: So try doing the method i gave. Use `webview.loadData()` instead of `webview.loadUrl()` and check